# Does Affectiva's Unity SDK support WebGL builds?

Tags: unity-game-engine, affdex-sdk

Aim:- To create a video-game with Unity3D integrated with Affectiva's emotion tracking [SDK](https://knowledge.affectiva.com/docs/getting-started-with-the-emotion-sdk-for-unity) and deploy it on a web-server for experimenting.

I downloaded the sample application called [EmoSurvival](https://github.com/Affectiva/EmoSurvival), which uses the Affectiva's SDK for emotion detection. I was able to make it work on a standalone PC build and also export the build for WebGL. The game worked fine on firefox, but the webcam didn't start to capture the real-time video for emotions. When I opened the console, I found the following logs there stating that Affectiva's Unity Asset doesn't support WebGL builds. I am lost now!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used this SDK before, but I believe that the message

> WebGLPlayer is not currently supported by Affectiva's Unity Asset

Is one written by the Affectiva developers. As such it would appear they have made the SDK check the platform it is run on, if an unsupported one it prints an error message instead of running.

Comment: Affectiva developer here -- just confirming that is correct.